# What is the difference between findByIdAndUpdate() and findOneAndUpdate(), in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Can anybody explain the difference between **findByIdAndUpdate()** and **findOneAndUpdate()** in mongoose.

And also the difference between findOneAndUpdate(**req.params.id**) and findOneAndUpdate(**{_id: req.params.id}**)?

Answer (score 22):

Check out the documentation for [findByIdAndUpdate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) and [findOneAndUpdate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) which clearly states:

> findByIdAndUpdate(id, ...) is equivalent to findOneAndUpdate({
>   _id: id }, ...).

So, really, `findByIdAndUpdate()` is just a convenient shorthand version for an update scenario that is likely to happen very often ("update by id").

With respect to your second question:

> And also the difference between findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id) and
>   findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id})?

The first one will simply crash as the first parameter to `findOneAndUpdate()` is expected to be a filter document. The second one will work and is equivalent to `findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id)` as already noted above.